# QLineEdit editingFinished signal twice when changing focus?

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qt-signals, qt-slot

I've found a few similar questions on this but these appear to refer to cases where a message box is used in the slot handler. In my case I am a bit stuck as I am getting the editFinished signal twice even when my slot handler is doing nothing.

For a test, I have an array of QLineEdit which use a signalMapper to connect the editingFinished() signals to a single slot. The signalMapper passes the array index so I can see where the signal came from.
eg:

```
testenter::testenter(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::testenter)
{
    // setup the UI according to the .h file
    ui->setupUi(this);

    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    // init the labels and edit boxes
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pm_label[i] = new QLabel(ui->scrollArea);
        QString text = QString("Number %1").arg(i);
        pm_label[i]->setText(text);
        pm_label[i]->setGeometry(10,20+i*30, 50, 20);
        pm_label[i]->show();

        pm_editBox[i] = new QLineEdit(ui->scrollArea);
        pm_editBox[i]->setGeometry(80,20+i*30, 50, 20);
        pm_editBox[i]->show();

        signalMapper->setMapping(pm_editBox[i], int(i));
        connect(pm_editBox[i], SIGNAL(editingFinished()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    }
    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(data_entry(int)));
}

void testenter::data_entry(int entry)
{
    //dummy
}
```

When run in the debugger, if I enter data into one box then either hit return or select another box with the mouse (ie change focus) , then it calls data_entry twice, the first time with index of the box that is losing focus and the 2nd time with the box which gets the focus.

So my question: Am I missing something? Is this expected behaviour or a bug?
If a bug, anyone know a way round it as I wanted to use this signal to do custom validation on data when it is entered (by either return, tab or mouse click to change focus).

Comment: Toby, Qt's signal slot mechanism can be a fun beast to wrestle with. What are the conditions you're encountering the behavior in? (i.e in a debugger with a break point, running without debugging and having a result occurring twice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, no this isn't expected behavior, i.e. selecting a `QLineEdit` should not cause it's `editingFinished` signal to be emitted.

There are a couple of possible things that may cause this problem:

- You've accidentally connected a signal twice to a slot
- The slot `map()` is causing the newly selected box to lose focus
- In the same vain, if you're debugging and using a break point to detect when the slots are getting called you may be causing the `QLineEdit` to lose focus when the active application changes from your `QWidget` to your debugger, again causing the signal to be sent again.

If you're having problems because of a doubly connected slot, which doesn't seem to be the case because you're specifically getting a signal from two different `QLineEdit`s, you can make sure that this isn't happening by specifying the connection type, the `connect` method actually has an additional optional argument at the end which allows you to change the type from a `DefaultConnection` to a `UniqueConnection`.

That being said, data validation is something that Qt has an established mechanism for, and I suggest that you use it if possible, look into extending the `QValidator` abstract base class [Ref Doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvalidator.html). You then tell each of your `QLineEdit`'s to use the same `validator`.

Comment: I've had another play and it appears your 3rd option is the problem. ie. the debugger is causing a focus change.
   qDebug() << "index " << entry;
works just fine. ie only one output per focus change.
I did spot the QValidator function but wanted to understand this behaviour before moving on. Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 3):

I have run into the same issue. It really does emit the signal twice, which is a known bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40 which however has not been addressed for a very long time.

Finally I found that the best solution in my case is to change the signal from `editingFinished` to `returnPressed`. As a side effect this behaves much more predictably from the user perspective. See also here: http://www.qtforum.org/article/33631/qlineedit-the-signal-editingfinished-is-emitted-twice.html?s=35f85b5f8ea45c828c73b2619f5750ba9c686190#post109943

Comment: It has been fixed in 5.14 alpha...a fourteen-year-old bug which was once ignored just because people didn't upvote it...

Answer (score 3):

The OP "found a few similar questions on this but these appear to refer to cases where a message box is used in the slot handler."   Well, that is my situation also, and here is where I ended up.  So, at the risk of going off topic...

In my situation, when my slot receives the `editingFinished` signal sent from the `QLineEdit`, I launch a modal `QMessageBox` to ask the user something.  The appearance of that message box is what triggers the `QLineEdit` to send the second, undesirable `editingFinished` signal.

A post in the bug report (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40) mentioned by @V.K. offers a workaround which helped me.  The following is my implementation of the workaround.  I let Qt magic mojo automatically connect the `QLineEdit` signal to my `MainWindow` slot.

```
void MainWindow::on_textbox_editingFinished( void )
{
  QLineEdit * pTextbox = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>( QObject::sender() );
  if ( !pTextbox->isModified() )
  {
    // Ignore undesirable signals.
    return;
  }

  pTextbox->setModified( false );

  // Do something with the text.
  doSomething( pTextbox->text() );
}

void MainWindow::doSomething( QString const & text )
{
  QMessageBox box( this );
  box.setStandardButtons( QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No );
  box.setText( "Are you sure you want to change that text value?" );
  if ( box.exec() == QMessageBox::Yes )
  {
    // Store the text.
    m_text = text;
  }
}
```